# I can't figure out the print function in Python in regards to dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pprint

I need help with a pprint function. I'm trying to make a program that records student ID numbers, their names, age, class rank, and gpa. I need to use a pprint() function to print the dictionary out. Here's my code so far.

```
student=dict()
student['ID']= raw_input ("What is your student ID number?")
student['name']= raw_input ("What is your name?") 
student['age']= raw_input ("How old are you?") 
student['rank']= raw_input ("What is your class rank?")
student['gpa']= raw_input ("What is your current GPA?")
```

What do I need to do? I've tried multiple variations of code, but nothings working. Thanks!

Comment: When claiming that your previous attempts do not work, it helps to share those previous attempts so we can point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Import [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) function from [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module and pass `student` to it:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(student)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the info, but you haven't printed anything at all.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(student)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `import pprint` and after you have gotten all the input print it out using `pprint.pprint(student)`